# How to support MBUnit tests in Resharper 7

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mbunit, gallio, resharper-7.0

Since I upgraded to VS2012, my R#5 license was not useful anymore. After downloading the R#7.0.1 and installing I realized that MbUnit no longer had builtin support for R#7.

Since I spent some time figuring out how to get the plugin running, I will post here to save anyone else the time (And in order for myself to find it back if I need to do it again...)

Answer (score 11):

A quick glance at the gallio source code at [Gallio.ResharperRunner](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/v3/src/Extensions/ReSharper/Gallio.ReSharperRunner) showed me that someone allready wrote the code. I could not find any distributions over at the [Gallio Build Server](http://ccnet.gallio.org/server/local/project/MbUnit%20v3/ViewProjectReport.aspx), so I pulled the latest R#Runner code from SVN. (I got rev 3359) and compiled the `v3\src\Extensions\ReSharper\Gallio.ReSharperRunner\Gallio.ReSharperRunner70.vs2010.csproj` in VS2012.

The project was changed so that it references `c:\Program Files\Gallio\bin\gallio.dll`, and I also changed the `Gallio.ReSharperRunner70.plugin` file to "Content" and PreserveNewest (Instead of do not copy)

Then I copied the following 3 files from the `debug\bin` folder to `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DotNet\vAny\Plugins`:

- Gallio.dll
- Gallio.ReSharperRunner70.dll
- Gallio.ReSharperRunner70.plugin

Voila - MbUnit tests can be executed in VS2012 using Resharper 7

NB: Not sure the ResharperRunner code is 100% stable - I seem to notice some glitches, but at least my tests are again appearing in R#.

I will upload the compiled files once I figure out how to attach files to a question.
Hmm - couldn't figure out how to do that, so I uploaded it to my website at http://www.albrektsen.net/Gallio.ResharperRunner70.zip

Comment: The current runner has several issues - I have created http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=900 over at the gallio bug-tracker.

Comment: What version of Gallio are you running? I tried your files and also tried downloading and building the source myself with the same modifications you made, however I get the following error in ReSharper: The plugin “StandardPluginFolders” file C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DotNet\vAny\Plugins\Gallio.ReSharperRunner70.plugin could not be loaded as valid a .NET assembly.

Comment: I am running Gallio3.4 build 11.
I have just re-uploaded the plugin I am currently using to http://www.albrektsen.net/Gallio.ResharperRunner70.zip - works ok for me. NB: It is not stable - as pointed out in the MbUnit issue, but works much better than the one compiled from trunk.

Comment: That build did the trick for me. I also realised I was still referencing the old MBUnit and Gallio DLLs. Thanks espenalb.

Comment: Applauding your effort! Works superbly for me.

Comment: Although I'm getting alot less information than before. For example, "Expected values to be equal". In 2010/R# 6 it said one is 5 the other is 3. I have to debugger it to find out. Why is that?

Comment: I know - that really sucks. I have not looked into it - will update this issue if I make any progress.

Comment: I installed and running works but debugging the unit test throws "Could not load file or assembly 'Gallio.ReSharperRunner71" See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550540/debug-unit-tests-using-resharper-7-for-mbunit-throws-an-exception Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

And here is a compiled plugin for Resharper 7.1:
http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=900#c9