# Debug Unit Tests using Resharper 7 for MBUnit throws an exception

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, versioning, mbunit, gallio

I have installed the Gallio Resharper Test Runner found at http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=900#c9 Per the instructions at [How to support MBUnit tests in Resharper 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982978/how-to-support-mbunit-tests-in-resharper-7).

When I right click inside of a unit test and click "Run Unit Tests" the tests run just fine. However when I right click and then click "Debug Unit Tests" I get:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Gallio.ReSharperRunner71,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How do I fix this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Gallio are you using? (I have hardcoded the plugin to link to Gallio.dll 3.4.11.0)

You need the following files in the plugin folder:

- Gallio.ReSharperRunner71.dll
- Gallio.ReSharperRunner71.plugin
- Gallio.dll
- Gallio.XmlSerializers.dll (Not sure if this one is required..)

Does that help?

Comment: That must have been it. Since I did not see any activity on Gallio for a while, I decided to just port the unit tests to NUnit. Without any references in the project to Gallio, the exception was still being thrown! So I ended up having to remove the files from resharper folder at C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\JetBrains\DotNet\vAny\Plugins: